# how to create 3 horizontal layout box's in content panel

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have to create three layout boxes as shown in the below image. Could anyone please help me on that.

[image]

2 horizontal layouts should be added in content widget.

Thanks
Sai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what the problem is. You just should use `VerticalLayoutContainer` and `HorizontalLayoutContainer` if understand what you want to do. Something like this:

```
ContentPanel cp=new ContentPanel();
cp.setHeadingText("Central Panel");
cp.setHeaderVisible(true);
cp.setBorders(true);
VerticalLayoutContainer vcon = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
HorzontalLayoutContainer hcon1 = new HorizontalLayoutContainer();
hcon1.add(panel1,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.25,-1);
hcon1.add(panel2,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.25,-1);
hcon1.add(panel3,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.25,-1);
hcon1.add(panel4,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.25,-1);
HorzontalLayoutContainer hcon2 = new HorizontalLayoutContainer();
hcon2.add(panel5,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.25,-1);
hcon2.add(panel6,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.25,-1);
hcon2.add(panel7,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.25,-1);
hcon2.add(panel8,new HorizontalLayoutData(0.25,-1);
vcon.add(hcon);
vcon.add(hcon);
cp.add(vcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question correctly but you could use **BorderLayout** in your panel and add three panels inside them with **BorderLayout.NORTH, BorderLayout.CENTER and BorderLayout.SOUTh**. That way you can get Horizontal layout 1 2 and 3.

Then you can use **FlowLayout** inside each panel for horizontal positioning